# Robotframework + AppiumLibrary: "Open Application" with two possible appActivity

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, robotframework

I'm using Robotframework(3.0) + AppiumLibary(1.4.1) to do Android testing and just encountered a situation that an APP will actually stop at different appActivity depends on it's logged in or not while using keyword **"Open Application"**

The flow of appActivity will be either

(1) **(APP witch not login yet) Open Application** --> Stop at *LoginActivity*  --> (input account/password to login) --> *MainPageActivity*

or

(2) **(APP which already logged in) Open Application** --> *LoginActivity* --> Stop at *MainPageActivity*

I've searched for lots of posts and most of answers are setting up **appActivity=LoginActivity** and **appWaitActivity=MainPageActivity**,

but the question is,

if I've already logged into this APP before and it will actually go into *MainPageActivity* automatically,

however if the APP isn't logged in yet, it will not go into *MainPageActivity* unless we key in account/password, which may cause fail as below:

```
WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created. 
(Original error: xxxx/.fragment.MainActivity never started. Current: xxxx/.LoginActivity)
```

So is there anyway to handle the possible different appActivity at start up or to deal with situation as above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in the AppWaitActivity to wait for your application:

example:

```
//the code bellow will work for YourApplication.LoginActivity and YourApplication.MainActivity
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AppWaitActivity, "YourApplication.*");
//or you can use this to "skip" the AppWaitActivity
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AppWaitActivity, "*");
```

Hope this helps.